# Vaadin - Highlight table selected cell/row

Tags: java, vaadin, cell, highlight

Is it possible to highlight the selected cell or the selected row in a Vaadin Table component?
I should perform this via java..so then when I catch a clicked item with an ItemClickListener I should push a customized background only to the selected cell (or row).
Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Built-in themes for Vaadin usually support specific style for selected row in vaadin table.

If you want to apply custom style on selected row you can do it through CSS:

```
.v-table tr.v-selected {
    background-color: #5B677D;
    color: #fff;
}
```

**Prerequisite:** [Chapter 8.4 "Creating and Using Themes" from Book of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.creating.html)

Comment: hey,how can i overwrite a style created by a theme? for example i have a theme already installed and how can i overwrite the v-selected made by that theme. Tnx

Comment: @VasileSurdu AFAIK, you're expected to extend the existing theme (i.e. create new custom theme) and then overwrite styles. You can also [add style names](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractComponent.html#addStyleName(java.lang.String)) to your components and then create custom component-specific selectors without overriding theme styles.

Comment: i found the solution,  .v-table tr.v-selected.v-selected{
 background:#EEEEEE;
 color:black;
}